# Using AWS traffic policy to setup weighted routing from a DNS record to two CloudFront distributions

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, network-traffic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHKNR.png)

I'm not sure if it just isn't possible, but why is it an option in the flow if it wasn't? I think the other option I saw was to setup a Lambda@edge function, but some of the material I've seen on it seemed a little complex. Any guidance will help!

I've set the before mentioned traffic policy and set the Type A DNS value, but it doesn't seem to be evenly splitting the traffic between the two cloudfront distributions.